# To convert categorical data to numerical data without One Hot encoding

Tags: python, data-science, probability, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I have a Data Matrix X which has a column or feature name `Country` . In this feature, there are **10 different countries listed**. There are 20k rows with 1 country in each row under column Country.  Its a Binary Classification problem with `0` or `1` as y's output.

I want to convert this **country feature into numerical** value but not by One hot encoding.

Method to follow:

1. let us suppose India occurs 5 times with 0 class labels and 3 times with 1 class labels And USA  occurs 7 times with 0 class labels and 5 times with 1 class labels in the country columns.
2. Now Converting into 2 dimensions as Country_0  and Country_1.

```
Line-1  ,    Row no.  , Country  ,Country_0 , Country_1   ,  Class_labels
Line 2  ,    1st row  ,  india  ,    5/8    ,   3/8       ,    0
Line 3  ,    2nd row  ,  usa    ,    7/12   ,   5/12      ,    1
```

How to convert it into 2 dimensions with probability value.
I have written Line 1 , line 2 and line 3 in tabular format .

Comment: you can use   get_dummies()

Comment: Can you please share the code ?

Comment: I think he's referring to Panda's [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html). But that's literally One hot encoding, which I understand you're not interested in, right?

Comment: Haven't thought this through, but I would think of somehing in the lines of groupby('country') + value_counts(normalize=True). The normalize in the value_counts returns the relative frequencies of the unique values. ([value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)

Comment: I think that get_dummies will not be right here , As it will gives the 0 or 1 value for each row.. And it will not count the country with 0 label and 1 label and will not give probability value.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment: stack/unstack operations may be needed. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51799866) may help.

Comment: This question is difficult to understand as currently written.  While some information is provided -- the inputs, task, and expected outputs are not yet sufficiently described for an average practitioner to follow.